# Haskell: a for loop for a REPL

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I am trying to write a something like a repl in Haskell and I want to replicate this code in C:

```c
for (int c = getc(stdin); c != 'e'; c = getc(stdin)) {
        printf("I got %c!\n", c);
}
```

I could use recursion but I am afraid of exeeding the limit.

Comment: Try it, and come back when you have exceeded the limit (with some info about how you managed that). We can't help fix code you haven't written.

Comment: Haskell does not work with a call stack, so there is no recursion limit like in C/Java/... What *can* happen is that you are building an expression that eventually no longer fits in memory, but if you thus ensure that you are not accumulating an expression, you can keep recursing.

Comment: You can also get a stack overflow, but it's a different kind of stack (and indeed not going to be a problem in this case). For example, `> iterate succ 0 !! 100000000    *** Exception: stack overflow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *should* use recursion.  Haskell is designed to handle recursion without limits, and recursion can and should be used even for effectively infinite loops (e.g., event processing loops or REPL loops).

So, you could more or less write your program as follows:

```
main = do
  txt <- getLine
  if txt /= "exit" then do
    putStrLn $ "I got " ++ txt ++ "!"
    main
  else do
    return ()
```

giving:

```
$ ./repl
foo
I got foo!
bar
I got bar!
exit
$
```

I've written it to grab a whole line of input instead of single character, since there are typically issues with buffered input when trying to grab input character by character.  This infinite recursion works fine and will not exceed any limit no matter how many billions of lines it processes before exiting.

In most real-world programs, you don't want the whole main program to loop, so you typically write something like the following.  Here, I've used `when` which is a nicer looking way of writing the pattern `if xxx then yyy else return ()`.

```
import Control.Monad  -- for definition of "when"

main = do
  -- initialization
  putStrLn $ "Welcome to my REPL!"
  -- start the main loop
  loop
  -- clean up
  putStrLn $ "Thanks so much for using my REPL!"

-- definition of main loop
loop = do
  txt <- getLine
  when (txt /= "exit") $ do
    putStrLn $ "I got " ++ txt ++ "!"
    loop
```